# MATLAB Cell2Mat conversion row wise

Tags: matlab

Say i have an array `A={[2x3],[3x3],[2x3]}`.
I'd to know how to convert this into a matrix like `a=[2x3;3x3;1x3]`

Example:

```
A={[1 1 1;2 2 2],[3 3 3;4 4 4;5 5 5],[6 6 6]}
```

to be converted to

```
B=[1 1 1;2 2 2;3 3 3;4 4 4;5 5 5;6 6 6]
```

.

Answer (score 5):

In the example you wrote you need to transpose A in order to use `cell2mat` :

```
cell2mat(A')
```

will output `B` as wanted